# WPF - collapse item in ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, events, binding, visibility

Thanks for your time reading my thread.

I am using VS2012, WFP, and .net4.5 on Windows 7 64bit

I have a ListView control with xaml in following:

```
<ListView Name="lvViewerControl"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=ViewType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      Background="{x:Null}"
                      BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                      Margin="2">
                <Label Name="lblView2D"
                       Width="40"
                       Height="40"
                       Margin="3"
                       Background="#FF595959"
                       Foreground="White"
                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Source="/CaptureSetupModule;component/Icons/2D.png" />
                </Label>
                <Label Name="lblView3D"
                       Width="40"
                       Height="40"
                       Margin="3"
                       Background="#FF595959"
                       Foreground="White"
                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Source="/CaptureSetupModule;component/Icons/3D.png" />
                </Label>
                <Label Name="lblViewTiles"                       
                       Width="40"
                       Height="40"
                       Margin="3"
                       Background="#FF595959"
                       Foreground="White"
                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                       Visibility="{Binding Path=XYCtrlVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}">
                    <Image Source="/CaptureSetupModule;component/Icons/Tile.png" />
                </Label>
            </ListView>
```

Now I want to collapse the third item, `lblViewTiles`. I tried to combine its `Visibility` to a bool, then do the boo to visibility conversion, but it did not work. What I mean by not work is that the `Visiblity` only collapses when the program starts. Afterwards, not matter how the binding variable (`Visiblity`) changes,  and the value does change to `Collapsed`, but the `lblViewTiles` still in the `ListView` control, no UI change.

Update:

The `DataContex` of the ListView is binded to `CaptureSetupModules` class, not `LiveVM` . I simply created a CaptureSetupModules  in `MasterView` class,

In MasterView class

```
    CaptureSetupModules _captureVM = new CaptureSetupModules();
    ...

LiveVM _liveVM = new LiveVM;
      if (ndList.Count > 0)
                {
                    xyBorder.Visibility = ndList[0].Attributes["Visibility"].Value.Equals("Visible") ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
                    tilesControlBorder.Visibility = ndList[0].Attributes["Visibility"].Value.Equals("Visible") ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;               
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                       new Action(
                           delegate()
                           {

                               _captureVM.XYCtrlVisible = ndList[0].Attributes["Visibility"].Value.Equals("Visible") ? true:false;

                           }
                       )
                   );               
                }
```

And here is my converter:

```
public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var flag = false;
            if (value is bool)
            {
                flag = (bool)value;
            }
            else if (value is bool?)
            {
                var nullable = (bool?)value;
                flag = nullable.GetValueOrDefault();
            }
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                if (bool.Parse((string)parameter))
                {
                    flag = !flag;
                }
            }
            if (flag)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
```

This code only makes the item collapsed the first time when the program starts , and it loads the visibility from the xml file. Afterwards, not matter how the XYCtrlVisible, which is the visibility binding, is changed, the UI show no response. The item is always there, or not there.

It is probably a little messy here, let me know if you need anything else. I am pretty confused myself too. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the part of the code that does not work? I don't see any `Visibility` triggers

Comment: I modified the post as you pointed out,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to look at `Converters` for `WPF`

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Boolean)
        {
                return ((bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

A sample usage in `XAML`

```
<StackPanel>
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVis" />
</StackPanel.Resources>

<CheckBox x:Name="chkShowDetails" Content="Show Details" />
<StackPanel x:Name="detailsPanel" 
            Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkShowDetails, 
                         Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}">
</StackPanel>
```

More information can be found [here](http://wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html).

Comment: I am trying to bind the visibility to some IsCheck of some nearby component. I am trying to bind to a variable. The bind is OK, it is just the visibility is not changing.

Comment: When you mean the "Bind is OK" which binding? I don't see the part in your code where you set the `lblViewTiles` to `Collapsed?`

Comment: The line:_liveVM.XYCtrlVisible = ndList[0].Attributes["Visibility"].Value.Equals("Visible") ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; sets the visibility to collapsed. I appreciate your example, but it seems pretty far from my case. I am a newbie to WPF, so I appreciate if something much more tailored here. –

Comment: You were asking if there was an easy way to manipulate the visibility of the control. Using `Converters` with `MVVM` will make it easy. I am guessing that `_liveVM` is the `DataContext` of the `ListView` and not the `Label` that's why it is not updating the `Visibility`.

Comment: Any idea how I can find the DataContext for the label?

Comment: How did you set the `DataContext` of the `ListView` ? If you did the binding for the `ItemsSource` i.e., List<Something> then the `DataContext` of each `ListViewItem` is each `Something`.